# nameNode/JournalNode/zkfc/dataNode processes received signal 15 at the same time

Tags: hadoop

the following is log:

```
dataNode31： received signal 15 when normally working

2023-04-20 12:19:16,899 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500502_1759678, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=2:\[10.69.37.33:9866, 10.69.37.32:9866\]\]  (BlockReceiver.java:(1506)) - PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500502_1759678, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=2:\[10.69.37.33:9866, 10.69.37.32:9866\] terminating

2023-04-20 12:19:27,290 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[DataXceiver for client DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1496294081_16 at /10.69.37.32:52326 \[Receiving block BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679\]\]  (DataXceiver.java:(747)) - Receiving BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679 src: /10.69.37.32:52326 dest: /10.69.37.31:9866

2023-04-20 12:19:27,293 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace \[PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE\]  (BlockReceiver.java:(1533)) - src: /10.69.37.32:52326, dest: /10.69.37.31:9866, bytes: 78013, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1496294081_16, offset: 0, srvID: 4518fdd4-5e97-45d7-8f74-03e4ff46d95c, blockid: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, duration(ns): 2885350

2023-04-20 12:19:27,294 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE\]  (BlockReceiver.java:(1506)) - PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE terminating

2023-04-20 12:19:31,937 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[SIGTERM handler\]  (LogAdapter.java:(75)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

2023-04-20 12:19:31,939 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[shutdown-hook-0\]  (LogAdapter.java:(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:

dataNode32： received signal 15 when normally working

2023-04-20 12:19:27,290 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[DataXceiver for client DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1496294081_16 at /10.69.37.33:48624 \[Receiving block BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679\]\]  (DataXceiver.java:(747)) - Receiving BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679 src: /10.69.37.33:48624 dest: /10.69.37.32:9866

2023-04-20 12:19:27,291 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient \[DataXceiver for client DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1496294081_16 at /10.69.37.33:48624 \[Receiving block BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679\]\]  (SaslDataTransferClient.java:(239)) - SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false

2023-04-20 12:19:27,296 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace \[PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=1:\[10.69.37.31:9866\]\]  (BlockReceiver.java:(1533)) - src: /10.69.37.33:48624, dest: /10.69.37.32:9866, bytes: 78013, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1496294081_16, offset: 0, srvID: 88b6ea5c-9fa5-4f50-a8c2-44a44a52465a, blockid: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, duration(ns): 3105983

2023-04-20 12:19:27,296 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=1:\[10.69.37.31:9866\]\]  (BlockReceiver.java:(1506)) - PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=1:\[10.69.37.31:9866\] terminating

2023-04-20 12:19:31,939 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[SIGTERM handler\]  (LogAdapter.java:(75)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

2023-04-20 12:19:31,942 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[shutdown-hook-0\]  (LogAdapter.java:(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:

dataNode33： received signal 15 when normally working

2023-04-20 12:19:27,287 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[DataXceiver for client DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1496294081_16 at /10.69.37.36:44796 \[Receiving block BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679\]\]  (DataXceiver.java:(747)) - Receiving BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679 src: /10.69.37.36:44796 dest: /10.69.37.33:9866

2023-04-20 12:19:27,288 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient \[DataXceiver for client DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1496294081_16 at /10.69.37.36:44796 \[Receiving block BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679\]\]  (SaslDataTransferClient.java:(239)) - SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false

2023-04-20 12:19:27,295 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace \[PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=2:\[10.69.37.32:9866, 10.69.37.31:9866\]\]  (BlockReceiver.java:(1533)) - src: /10.69.37.36:44796, dest: /10.69.37.33:9866, bytes: 78013, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1496294081_16, offset: 0, srvID: 684b732c-0f96-497f-8a97-0c4917fa9a4d, blockid: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, duration(ns): 3261770

2023-04-20 12:19:27,295 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=2:\[10.69.37.32:9866, 10.69.37.31:9866\]\]  (BlockReceiver.java:(1506)) - PacketResponder: BP-1118324521-10.69.37.29-1610418967470:blk_1075500503_1759679, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=2:\[10.69.37.32:9866, 10.69.37.31:9866\] terminating

2023-04-20 12:19:31,940 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[SIGTERM handler\]  (LogAdapter.java:(75)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

2023-04-20 12:19:31,945 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode \[shutdown-hook-0\]  (LogAdapter.java:(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:

nameNode29： received signal 15 when normally working

2023-04-20 12:19:16,899 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange \[IPC Server handler 4 on default port 8020\]  (FSNamesystem.java:(2948)) - DIR\* completeFile: /AGFS/LZRCB/loan/loan/customer/YCC_2304201143029_OGK15K/yslp_invest_last_12_income_flow/certificate_of_cash_bank_deposit/16819643568819FXPIH.jpg is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1496294081_16

2023-04-20 12:19:27,282 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange \[IPC Server handler 8 on default port 8020\]  (FSDirWriteFileOp.java:(798)) - BLOCK\* allocate blk_1075500503_1759679, replicas=10.69.37.33:9866, 10.69.37.32:9866, 10.69.37.31:9866 for /AGFS/LZRCB/rce/user/YCC_2304201209059_JDV9EK/ysrp_risk_scheme_inst/YRSI_2304201218011_PBAIZ2/risk_report_docx/16819643672733LO9DE.docx

2023-04-20 12:19:27,295 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange \[IPC Server handler 3 on default port 8020\]  (FSNamesystem.java:(2948)) - DIR\* completeFile: /AGFS/LZRCB/rce/user/YCC_2304201209059_JDV9EK/ysrp_risk_scheme_inst/YRSI_2304201218011_PBAIZ2/risk_report_docx/16819643672733LO9DE.docx is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1496294081_16

2023-04-20 12:19:31,937 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode \[SIGTERM handler\]  (LogAdapter.java:(75)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

2023-04-20 12:19:31,940 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode \[shutdown-hook-0\]  (LogAdapter.java:(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:

nameNode30： received signal 15 when normally working

2023-04-20 12:17:45,840 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage \[Edit log tailer\]  (FSEditLogLoader.java:(178)) - Start loading edits file http://GS1MB019.gsrcu:8480/getJournal?jid=mycluster&segmentTxId=24286951&storageInfo=-65%3A1765377379%3A1610418967470%3ACID-0abed7a3-6fd1-4b6d-b414-202c9b7bdea2&inProgressOk=true, http://GS1MB020.gsrcu:8480/getJournal?jid=mycluster&segmentTxId=24286951&storageInfo=-65%3A1765377379%3A1610418967470%3ACID-0abed7a3-6fd1-4b6d-b414-202c9b7bdea2&inProgressOk=true maxTxnsToRead = 9223372036854775807

2023-04-20 12:17:45,840 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream \[Edit log tailer\]  (RedundantEditLogInputStream.java:(186)) - Fast-forwarding stream 'http://GS1MB019.gsrcu:8480/getJournal?jid=mycluster&segmentTxId=24286951&storageInfo=-65%3A1765377379%3A1610418967470%3ACID-0abed7a3-6fd1-4b6d-b414-202c9b7bdea2&inProgressOk=true, http://GS1MB020.gsrcu:8480/getJournal?jid=mycluster&segmentTxId=24286951&storageInfo=-65%3A1765377379%3A1610418967470%3ACID-0abed7a3-6fd1-4b6d-b414-202c9b7bdea2&inProgressOk=true' to transaction ID 24286951

2023-04-20 12:17:45,840 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream \[Edit log tailer\]  (RedundantEditLogInputStream.java:(186)) - Fast-forwarding stream 'http://GS1MB019.gsrcu:8480/getJournal?jid=mycluster&segmentTxId=24286951&storageInfo=-65%3A1765377379%3A1610418967470%3ACID-0abed7a3-6fd1-4b6d-b414-202c9b7bdea2&inProgressOk=true' to transaction ID 24286951

2023-04-20 12:17:45,872 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage \[Edit log tailer\]  (FSEditLogLoader.java:(188)) - Loaded 1 edits file(s) (the last named http://GS1MB019.gsrcu:8480/getJournal?jid=mycluster&segmentTxId=24286951&storageInfo=-65%3A1765377379%3A1610418967470%3ACID-0abed7a3-6fd1-4b6d-b414-202c9b7bdea2&inProgressOk=true, http://GS1MB020.gsrcu:8480/getJournal?jid=mycluster&segmentTxId=24286951&storageInfo=-65%3A1765377379%3A1610418967470%3ACID-0abed7a3-6fd1-4b6d-b414-202c9b7bdea2&inProgressOk=true) of total size 15885.0, total edits 109.0, total load time 33.0 ms

2023-04-20 12:19:31,939 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode \[SIGTERM handler\]  (LogAdapter.java:(75)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

2023-04-20 12:19:31,943 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode \[shutdown-hook-0\]  (LogAdapter.java:(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:

journalNode29： received signal 15 when normally working

2023-04-20 12:15:45,588 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.TransferFsImage \[qtp1484673893-23\]  (TransferFsImage.java:(397)) - Sending fileName: /home/ap/hadoop/ha-hadoop/journaldata/mycluster/current/edits_0000000000024286741-0000000000024286950, fileSize: 30055. Sent total: 30055 bytes. Size of last segment intended to send: -1 bytes.

2023-04-20 12:17:17,843 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNodeSyncer \[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNodeSyncer

Lambda$21/2008919665@d67370\](JournalNodeSyncer.java:(232))?SyncingJournal/0.0.0.0:8485with/10.69.37.29:8485,journalid:mycluster2023?04?2012:17:45,657INFOorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FileJournalManager\[IPCServerhandler3ondefaultport8485\](FileJournalManager.java:(145))?Finalizingeditsfile/home/ap/hadoop/ha?hadoop/journaldata/mycluster/current/editsinprogress0000000000024286951?\>/home/ap/hadoop/ha?hadoop/journaldata/mycluster/current/edits0000000000024286951?00000000000242870592023?04?2012:17:45,866INFOorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.TransferFsImage\[qtp1484673893?18\](TransferFsImage.java:(397))?SendingfileName:/home/ap/hadoop/ha?hadoop/journaldata/mycluster/current/edits0000000000024286951?0000000000024287059,fileSize:15885.Senttotal:15885bytes.Sizeoflastsegmentintendedtosend:?1bytes.2023?04?2012:19:17,892INFOorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNodeSyncer\[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNodeSyncer

Lambda$21/2008919665@d67370\]  (JournalNodeSyncer.java:(232)) - Syncing Journal /0.0.0.0:8485 with /10.69.37.30:8485, journal id: mycluster

2023-04-20 12:19:31,937 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNode \[SIGTERM handler\]  (LogAdapter.java:(75)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

2023-04-20 12:19:31,940 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNode \[shutdown-hook-0\]  (LogAdapter.java:(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:

journalNode30： received signal 15 when normally working

2023-04-20 12:15:45,388 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FileJournalManager \[IPC Server handler 0 on default port 8485\]  (FileJournalManager.java:(145)) - Finalizing edits file /home/ap/hadoop/ha-hadoop/journaldata/mycluster/current/edits_inprogress_0000000000024286741 -\> /home/ap/hadoop/ha-hadoop/journaldata/mycluster/current/edits_0000000000024286741-0000000000024286950

2023-04-20 12:17:18,142 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNodeSyncer \[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNodeSyncer

Lambda$21/1508065515@3debeda5\](JournalNodeSyncer.java:(232))?SyncingJournal/0.0.0.0:8485with/10.69.37.29:8485,journalid:mycluster2023?04?2012:17:45,670INFOorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FileJournalManager\[IPCServerhandler0ondefaultport8485\](FileJournalManager.java:(145))?Finalizingeditsfile/home/ap/hadoop/ha?hadoop/journaldata/mycluster/current/editsinprogress0000000000024286951?\>/home/ap/hadoop/ha?hadoop/journaldata/mycluster/current/edits0000000000024286951?00000000000242870592023?04?2012:19:18,203INFOorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNodeSyncer\[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNodeSyncer

Lambda$21/1508065515@3debeda5\]  (JournalNodeSyncer.java:(232)) - Syncing Journal /0.0.0.0:8485 with /10.69.37.30:8485, journal id: mycluster

2023-04-20 12:19:31,939 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNode \[SIGTERM handler\]  (LogAdapter.java:(75)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

2023-04-20 12:19:31,944 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNode \[shutdown-hook-0\]  (LogAdapter.java:(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:

ZKFC29：received signal 15 when normally working

2023-04-20 11:29:54,026 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector \[main-EventThread\]  (ActiveStandbyElector.java:(990)) - But old node has our own data, so don't need to fence it.

2023-04-20 11:29:54,026 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector \[main-EventThread\]  (ActiveStandbyElector.java:(915)) - Writing znode /hadoop-ha/mycluster/ActiveBreadCrumb to indicate that the local node is the most recent active...

2023-04-20 11:29:54,029 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController \[main-EventThread\]  (ZKFailoverController.java:(385)) - Trying to make NameNode at GS1MB019.gsrcu/10.69.37.29:8020 active...

2023-04-20 11:29:56,416 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController \[main-EventThread\]  (ZKFailoverController.java:(392)) - Successfully transitioned NameNode at GS1MB019.gsrcu/10.69.37.29:8020 to active state

2023-04-20 12:19:31,937 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController \[SIGTERM handler\]  (LogAdapter.java:(75)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

2023-04-20 12:19:31,940 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController \[shutdown-hook-0\]  (LogAdapter.java:(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:

ZKFC30:  received signal 15 when normally working

2023-04-20 11:30:03,261 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController \[Health Monitor for NameNode at GS1MB020.gsrcu/10.69.37.30:8020\]  (ZKFailoverController.java:(893)) - Local service NameNode at GS1MB020.gsrcu/10.69.37.30:8020 entered state: SERVICE_HEALTHY

2023-04-20 11:30:03,277 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController \[main-EventThread\]  (ZKFailoverController.java:(489)) - ZK Election indicated that NameNode at GS1MB020.gsrcu/10.69.37.30:8020 should become standby

2023-04-20 11:30:03,289 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController \[main-\`your text\`EventThread\]  (ZKFailoverController.java:(494)) - Successfully transitioned NameNode at GS1MB020.gsrcu/10.69.37.30:8020 to standby state

2023-04-20 12:19:31,939 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController \[SIGTERM handler\]  (LogAdapter.java:(75)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

2023-04-20 12:19:31,942 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController \[shutdown-hook-0\]  (LogAdapter.java:(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:

I have five servers,the last numbers of their ip are: 29/30/31/32/33 . nameNode/JournalNode/zkfc are deployed on 29/3 .dataNodes are deployed on 31/32/33.YARN/MAPREDUCE not deployed
```

the system had been running normally from  2021-03-22 to 2023-04-16,but since we rebooted the servers on 2023-04-16, nameNode/JournalNode/zkfc/dataNode processes all are suddenly shutdown very  frequently, often 3 times per day . i collected OS audit log for kill command,it is user 'hadoop' who kill the nameNode/JournalNode/zkfc/dataNode processes.  it seems that the HADOOP executes stop-dfs automatically because all the processes received signal 15 at the same time

What happened?